# Different cursor for different Vim modes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, vim, psreadline

I added Vim bindings to my Powershell using `PSReadline` module as shown [in this Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/a/779653/602610). The problem after this was that there wasn't any visual indicator for the different modes of Vim.

I just wanted different cursors for the 'command' and the other modes. Block cursor for command mode and line cursor for other modes. So I searched around and found this in the official Microsoft docs: [Use ViModeChangeHandler to display Vi mode changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.1#example-6--use-vimodechangehandler-to-display-vi-mode-changes)

```
# This example emits a cursor change VT escape in response to a Vi mode change.

function OnViModeChange {
    if ($args[0] -eq 'Command') {
        # Set the cursor to a blinking block.
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "`e[1 q"
    } else {
        # Set the cursor to a blinking line.
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "`e[5 q"
    }
}
Set-PSReadLineOption -ViModeIndicator Script -ViModeChangeHandler $Function:OnViModeChange
```

I simply copy-pasted this at the bottom of my `$PROFILE` file after running `ise $PROFILE`.

Surprisingly, I got an error when I tried to source my `$PROFILE`:

```
> & $PROFILE
Set-PSReadLineOption : Cannot bind parameter 'ViModeIndicator'. Cannot convert value "Script" to type
"Microsoft.PowerShell.ViModeStyle". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name Script to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of
the following enumerator names and try again:
None, Prompt, Cursor"
At C:\Users\user\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:27 char:39
+ Set-PSReadLineOption -ViModeIndicator Script -ViModeChangeHandler $Fu ...
+                                       ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PSReadLineOption], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.SetPSReadLineOption
```

Googling [*"Set-PSReadLineOption : Cannot bind parameter 'ViModeIndicator'. Cannot convert value "Script" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.ViModeStyle"."*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Set-PSReadLineOption+%3A+Cannot+bind+parameter+%27ViModeIndicator%27.+Cannot+convert+value+%22Script%22+to+type+%22Microsoft.PowerShell.ViModeStyle%22.) doesn't result in any useful results (just 2 results actually).

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error tells you what to do: "Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: None, Prompt, Cursor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was following the instructions given in the Server Fault post I ran:

```
Install-Module PsReadline -Scope CurrentUser
```

And was notified that `PsReadline` was already installed on my system. It asked me to append `-Force` at the end of the command to force it to update. At the time, I didn't append `-Force` and went along with the preinstalled version.

Thanks to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315479/different-cursor-for-different-vim-modes-in-powershell?noredirect=1#comment120738152_68315479):

> The error tells you what to do: "Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: None, Prompt, Cursor"

I figured out the problem. I went back to the documentation and checked the docs for `-ViModeIndicator` and found:

> -ViModeIndicator
>
> This option sets the visual indication for the current Vi mode. Either
> insert mode or command mode.
>
> The valid values are as follows:
>
> ```
> None: There`s no indication.
> Prompt: The prompt changes color.
> Cursor: The cursor changes size.
> Script: User-specified text is printed.
> ```

This contradicted the output I was getting in my Powershell, saying, *"[...]  one of the following enumerator names and try again: None, Prompt, Cursor"*. (Notice that Script is not mentioned).

So I understood that I must be using the wrong version of [`PsReadline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7.1), as stated in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The PSReadLine module contains cmdlets that let you customize the command-line editing environment in PowerShell. PowerShell 7.1 shipped with PSReadLine v2.1. **These articles document PSReadLine v2.1.**

Hence to solve this use:

```
Install-Module PsReadline -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

while installing `PsReadline`.